# How to find the focal distances of the point $P(5,4\sqrt { 3} )$ on the ellipse $16{ x }^{ 2 }+25{ y }^{ 2 }=1600$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I have found the value of the eccentricity $e$ which is $0.6$ . How do I proceed?

Comment: Are these the distances to the focal points?

Comment: @mvw Focal distances here are the distances between one focus and the point and the other focus and the same point

Answer (score 1):

Focal points on a ellipe are (ae,0) or (-ae,0)

Here a is 100 .

From this you will get the focus . Now ypuse the distance formula to find the distance between the points .

You can try [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/jee-preparation)